# Eclipse milo - How to handle data (nodes) visibility in OPCUA so that different users see different data?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I am in the process of analizing how to set up an OPCUA server in the cloud, and one of the challenges is data visibility. As data visibility, I mean that a user/customer can see certain data/devices that only belongs to him, and the same will apply to other users.

So the node creation process will depend on who the connected user is.

How can this be implemented in the best way according to OPCUA and specifically eclipse milo? Is it different namespaces for each customer? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different namespaces per customer would be an okay approach, but whether you do that or not you ultimately need to be examining the Session during the execution of Browse, Read, Write, and other services to determine which User is connected and what rights they have.

Comment: If examining the session is required anyway, is it common/recommended to use the same namespace and just add/remove nodes/services depending on the user? Thanks!

Comment: I think that's fine, but if this were me I'd explore the idea of running a different server per customer rather than mixing data and dealing with the potential for one customer to access or see another's data.